Serial port output is always null when developing with platformio on nexys4 ddr
target
to output "Hello world" thru the serial port
platform.ini config
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:swervolf_nexys]
platform = chipsalliance
board = swervolf_nexys
framework = wd-riscv-sdk

monitor_speed = 115200

board_build.bitstream_file = ./rvfpga.bit

address editor

code to be exec
#if defined(D_NEXYS_A7)
   #include <bsp_printf.h>
   #include <bsp_mem_map.h>
   #include <bsp_version.h>
#else
   PRE_COMPILED_MSG("no platform was defined")
#endif
#include <psp_api.h>


#define READ_IO(addr)  (volatile unsigned int *)(addr)
#define WRITE_IO(addr) (volatile unsigned int *)( addr)
#define inline_assembly()  asm("ori $0, $0, 0x1234")

#define UART_BASE 0x80111000


#define rbr 0*4
#define ier 1*4
#define fcr 2*4
#define lcr 3*4
#define mcr 4*4
#define lsr 5*4
#define msr 6*4
#define scr 7*4

#define thr rbr
#define iir fcr
#define dll rbr
#define dlm ier

void delay()
{
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<100000;++i);
}

int main()
{
    //printfNexys("hello world\n");
   *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + lcr) = 0x00000080; // LCR[7]  is 1
   delay();
   *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + dll) = 27;  // DLL msb. 115200 at 50MHz. Formula is Clk/16/baudrate. From axi_uart manual.
   delay();
   *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + dlm) = 0x00000000;  // DLL lsb.
   delay();
   *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + lcr) = 0x00000003;  // LCR register. 8n1 parity disabled
   delay();
   *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + ier) = 0x00000000;  // IER register. disable interrupts
   delay();

   while (1) 
   {
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000048;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000065;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000006C;  
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000006C;  
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000006F;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000020;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000077;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000006F;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000072;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000006C; 
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x00000064;
      delay();
      *WRITE_IO(UART_BASE + thr) = 0x0000000A; 
      delay();              

   }
   return 0;
}

output

target: output "Hello world" thru the serial port
i've tried with other's bitstream by changing the address of UART_BASE, it worked.So the problem may be on the address of UART_BASE, but i cannot find any docs to solve the problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

the line below should be annotated, and the problem is solved.
   // WRITE_IO((UART_BASE + dlm), 0x00000000);  // DLL lsb.

